# Older Devices compatibility for new iOS app

Tags: ios

After recently upgrade an app , we found that the installs are dropping and upon some analysis we found out that we no longer get new installs from older devices (iPhone 5 + iPhone 4s on iOS 10+ and iOS9.3+) after the upgrade. Is this related to the 64-bit only change, and does it mean older devices are no longer able to install our app?? The minimum support OS version for our new app upgrade is still put at `iOS 9.1.`

**How to make an app that properly supports older devices?**

Answer (score 0):

Add below entries in valid architectures
Select Target > Select Build Settings > Architectures

[image]